Mongoose skip and limit for objects inside an array
Before mongoose I worked with sequelize. Decided to try mongoose and figured out that in my code ignored skip and limit options.
Here is my model:
const User = new Schema({
  login: { type: String, reqiried: true, unique: true },
  email: { type: String, reqiried: true, unique: true },
  password: { type: String, require: true },
  avatar: { type: String },
  posts: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Post" }],
  likedPosts: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Post" }],
  repostedPosts: [
    {
      post: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Post" },
      text: { type: String },
    },
  ],
});

And service code:
export const getReposted = async (userId, limit, skip) => {
  const reposted = await User.findOne({ _id: userId })
    .populate({
      path: `repostedPosts`,
      skip: `${skip}`,
      limit: `${limit}`,
      populate: {
        path: "post",
        populate: {
          path: "author",
          select: "login",
        },
      },
    })
    .select("repostedPosts -_id");

  return reposted;
};

But its returned all of the objects inside an array.
Same code worked perfectly for likedPosts and posts.
I'll be glad if you help.
Tried everything except changing the document structure, which will probably work, but I'd like to know if I'm missing something.

You probably need to remodel your data and change your schema design.
At the minute you are not populating repostedPosts because repostedPosts is an array of Objects not ObjectIds. The mongoose Model.populate() method expects one or more ObjectIds from the path you wish to populate.
To fix this initial problem update your query to populate repostedPosts.post  and then you can populate the author from those populated posts.
export const getReposted = async (userId, limit, skip) => {
  const reposted = await User.findOne({ _id: userId })
    .populate({
      path: "repostedPosts.post",
      skip: skip,
      limit: limit,
      populate: {
        path: "author",
        select: "login"
      },
    })
    .select("repostedPosts -_id");
  return reposted;
};

However, because you wish to use skip and limit while populating, you will likely get null values for the ones you are skipping and likewise from the ones you are excluding via the limit. Maybe that is OK for you and you won't need to remodel. Or maybe you can just slice the ones you want to keep from the result by using Array.slice() like so:
export const getReposted = async (userId, limit, skip) => {
  const reposted = await User.findOne({ _id: userId })
    .populate({
      path: "repostedPosts.post",
      skip: skip,
      limit: limit,
      populate: {
        path: "author",
        select: "login"
      },
    })
    .select("repostedPosts -_id");
  reposted.repostedPosts = reposted.repostedPosts.slice(skip, skip+limit); //< use slice()
  return reposted;
};



Of all of them, only the slice works correctly, so I will use it, thanks!

Maybe I'm missing something, but I believe skip and limit are "Query Options" and not "Populate Options", which would make them properties of the options object in .populate. Does this work:
export const getReposted = async (userId, limit, skip) => {
  const reposted = await User.findOne({ _id: userId })
    .populate({
      path: `repostedPosts`,
      options: {
        skip: `${skip}`,
        limit: `${limit}`,
      },
      populate: {
        path: "post",
        populate: {
          path: "author",
          select: "login",
        },
      },
    })
    .select("repostedPosts -_id");

  return reposted;
};

Mongoose Source Code:

PopulateOptions
QueryOptions


Limit and skip can be used outside the options block, in other cases the same code works. But I tried it anyway, the result is the same.
